# Does Instagram API support get followers list and more?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working on an app, which does the below:

1. A user logins using instagram User creates content and shares it with a subset of her instagram followers ( say 3 out of 200)
2. Those 3 users get a message in their insta inbox and can click on a link
   and sign up on our app.

I am trying to find Insta API documentation, but I am unable to. Can someone experienced with Insta API's please guide to me to specific parts of the Instagram API documentation which can do What I am imagining?

Thanks

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-the-instagram-api--cms-23608

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you are trying to create is not possible by using official Instagram APIs. None of the APIs returns the list of followers for given user. It is also not possible to send a Direct message via Instagram API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api here is the introduction to Instagram Graph API. Right on the top of that page you will find possible use-case scenarios. 
There is also more limited Basic Display API which documentation and possible use-cases you can find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api